# How can I reuse these variables?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

Working with Flutter/Dart.

I have a function to get gps location called from a floating action button.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getCurrentLocation,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),

Position? _position;
  void _getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await _determinePosition();
    setState(() {
      _position = position;
      var lat = position.latitude.toString();
      var long = position.longitude.toString();
      print("New Lat: $lat");
      print("New Long: $long");
    });
  }
```

This is working ok but I would like to re-use the variables lat and long outside of this function in a different function or widget on the same page and possibly on another page as well.

My understanding is setState is not what I need for this as that is used to change the screen design upon detection.

My need for updated variables is to be able to POST them through a PHP server to get data from a database.

Here is what I have tried outside of the function, but the variables are empty.

```
async {
  try {
    var response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse("https://www.sample.com/sample.php"), body: {
      "latitude": lat,
      "longitude": long,
    });
    print(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this should have the [tag:javascript] tag on it?

Comment: @divibisan Looks more like TypeScript than JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think it's JS/TS...although the main thing is why do we have to *guess*?

Comment: Looks more like Dart/Flutter. At least the first one does

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it as flutter and thought that was enough.  I will edit to include the words.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class that support stream controllers and you can set and get data though them

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html

is very easy to implement, you can use [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) too or use state management with bloc or provider